# Visual Studio c++ local static "out of scope" in debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm running Visual Studio 2013, Express version.
When I hit a breakpoint in one of my functions, I can watch the local variables, but not the local static variables.  For example:

```
static int IcanSeeThis;
private: void foo()
    {
    int ThisIsVisibleToo;
    static int ThisIsOutOfScope = 0;

    // breakpoint here
    ThisIsOutOfScope++;
    ...
```

I can work around it by giving my variables global scope, but this is weird.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: using vs2015 i cannot replicate this. I have seen it before however and if I recall correctly, the absurd solution was to put the static's at the top of the scope..ie declare them ahead of any locals.